# Minimum number of additional weights required in order to weight items in range from 1 to 100

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a set of weights `S={w1,w2,w3}` and a range of weights, we need to determine whether the weights in `S` can be used to balance every weight in the range. If not, we need to add the minimum additional weights to `S` so that all of the weights in the range can be balanced.

For example:
Range is 1 to 5
S = {4,8,9}

The item with weight 1 can be balanced by putting the item on the left pan along with the 8, and put the 9 on the right pan.

[image]

`1` + 8 = 9
`3` + 9 = 8 + 4
`4`     = 4
`5` + 8 = 9 + 4

But 2 can't be balanced using the weights {4,8,9} so we need to add another weight. Adding a weight of 1 allows 2 to balanced with

`2` + 8 = 1 + 9

My question is there a mathematical algorithm that can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: please explain this line "1|8-9 -for 1 3|9 -8|4 -for 3 4|4 -for 4 5|8-9|4 for 5", it's all messed up

Comment: For item 1 whose weight is 1 the balance can be done by using weight 8 and the item itself on the left and using weight 9 on the right. Likewise for others.

Comment: An observation: each of the weights in `S` has three possible locations: on the left pan, on the right pan, or not used. This suggests a base-3 numbering system. It's easy to show that a set `S = {1,3,9,27,...}` can be used to balance any weight from 1 to the total weight of `S`.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes,but here we have been given with the set of weights and if possible we need to use these weights to weigh the range

Comment: @PrakharT The title doesn't actually match the question. Is the title correct that the range is always 1 to 100? Or is the range an input to the algorithm? And if the range is an input, then what are the constraints on the problem?

Comment: Yes the range is variable and can be 10**9

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are algorithms that would solve this. For clarity's sake, I'm assuming your use of the term "set" is the mathematical set, where all set elements are distinct, though this should not affect the below code all that much.
Breaking down the problem into 2 parts:

(1) Determine if the provided set of weights can be arranged on the scale such that the required range of integer values are covered

A solution to part (1), in python:
(to run, call   `check_range(int, int, [])`, where the first two args are the integer bounds of the range, low/high respectively, and the 3rd arg is a list of the weights in set s)

```
def get_possible_offsets(s=[]):
    #the variable set "temp" will hold the possible offsets that we can create by arranging the weights on the scale 
    temp=set()

    #optionally, we don't need to add any of the weights, ergo add value 0 by default
    temp.add(0)

    #per every weight in the given set of weights
    for weight in s:

        #take an iterable snapshot of our set of possible offsets
        l = list(temp)

        #for each value in that list, |i+/-w| the weight value
        for i in l:
            temp.add(i + weight)
            temp.add(abs(i - weight))

        #and also add the weight by itself
        temp.add(weight)

    return(temp)

def check_range(r_low=0, r_high=1, s=[]):
    #get the set of weight values available using the provided set of weights
    possible_offsets = get_possible_offsets(s)

    #list to store the required weight values not available using the provided set of weights
    missing_offsets = []

    #for each required weight in the range, check if that weight exists in our current possible offsets
    for i in range(r_low, r_high+1):
        if i not in possible_offsets:
            missing_offsets.append(i)

    #if we're not missing any values from the required range, then we are done!
    if len(missing_offsets) == 0:
        print ("Yes! The required range is covered by the provided weights.")
    else:
        print ("Tragically, the following weight offsets are not covered:",missing_offsets)
```

(2) If 1. is false, then determine the minimum required additional weights to complete the required range

Part (2) of the problem, I have not added a complete solution yet, however, we just need to take the `missing_offsets` list in the above code, and boil it down to the additional weight values that could be included in the set of `possible_offsets`, as performed in the lines of code:

```
        for i in l:
            temp.add(i + weight)
            temp.add(abs(i - weight))
```

This problem also sounds a lot like search-tree algos (though not binary), as well as combinatorics, so there are likely several efficient ways of calculating the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The set of absolute differences between each side of the scale is our range. Let's enumerate them for `S`, aggregating each element in turn (add and subtract each element to each previously seen absolute difference, then add the element itself as a difference):

```
S: {4, 8, 9}

up to element S_0:
4

up to element S_1:
4, 12, 8

up to element S_2:
4, 12, 8, 13, 5, 21, 3, 1, 17, 9
```

Now let's order them:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 17, 21
```

To cover our range, 1 to 5, we need to fill the gap between 1 and 3. Adding a 1 will add ±1 to every difference we can create.

Would it not be the case that to cover any range, we would need to add `ceil(k / 2)` 1's, where `k` is the maximum gap in our range, when considering our enumerated differences? In this case, ceil(1 / 2) = one 1?

As ruakh commented below, this is not the case. Any lower range we can build, in fact can be used to fill-in gaps anywhere, and the coverage of the filled-in range can be applied again to growing ranges. For example:

```
{1, 2} covers 1 to 3

Now add 7 and we've increased our
range to 1 - 10 by virtue of applying ±3 to 7

Now we can add 21 and achieve the
range 21 ± 10!
```

This points to the possibility of overlapping subproblems.

Comment: The last paragraph of this answer isn't right; that would be the right answer if we can *only* add 1s, but not necessarily if we can add arbitrary weights. For example, suppose that *S* is { 1, 2, 20 }; then it can be used to balance any integer 1-3 or 17-20, leaving a gap of size 13. The last paragraph of this answer says that we need to add seven 1s to *S*, but in fact we can completely fill the gap by adding just one 7.

Comment: @ruakh technically the last paragraph of this answer isn't either right or wrong; it's a question :) But thanks for a great observation, the kind I was hoping for. It implies that our independent ranges, 1-3, 17-23 (not 20) can be re-applied anywhere in the answer; thus when adding 7, we immediately fill the gap between 3 and 7 and 10, and with 1 to 10, 20 enables us to then fill 10-20. But how to build a solution?

Comment: Given that {1,2,7} covers the range 1 to 10, the next number is 21, since `21-10 = 11`. (`20-10=10` isn't needed since 10 is already covered.) The resulting set {1,2,7,21} covers 1 to 31. The next number is 63, then 189, etc.

Comment: @user3386109 oh, right; and that relates to your comment about base 3.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: OK, fair enough. :-)